# Making the transition from mysql_ to MySQLi or PDO

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, pdo, mysqli

I have been searching here and Google for how to change all my MYSQL scripts to MYSQLI or PDO starting just from the beginning. The thing is that for some reason I cannot understand because I am inexperienced and I cannot make a simple session work. Here is what I will start doing because I want to learn the new MYSQLi:

I picked the registration form ( I will not use it in public, my site is just for friends and no more people I choose who will be member and I sign em up )

```
<?php
/* instantiate our class, and select our database automatically */
$sql = mysqli('localhost','user','password','database');

/*
let's assume we've just received a form submission.
so we'll receive the information, and we'll escape it
this step is not necessary, but why not.
*/
$name  = $_POST['name'];
$age   = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

/* build the query, we'll use an insert this time */
$query = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO `tablename` VALUES ('?','?','?');");

/*
bind your parameters to your query
in our case, string integer string
*/
$query->bind_param("sis",$name,$age,$email);
/* execute the query, nice and simple */
$query->execute();
?>
```

This is ok for me easy to understand, now I cannot find a good example of user login, all examples I find are from expert developers and they mostly create so complex scripts that I dont even need it. Already installed many examples ready made and it feels like they are not really good.

What I have been waiting and looking for and searching 1 WEEK 12 hours a day is:

I want the user to simply login and then the script will have something simple like this:

PAGE START

```
HELLO <PHP ECHO USERNAME> <PHP ECHO AGE> <PHP ECHO ANYTHING FROM DB> 
THANKS

<?php
ELSE
IF USER IS NOT LOGGED IN
REDIRECT TO THE PAGE NOTMEMBER.PHP
?>
```

PAGE END

Why? Because that's the easy and simple way I use to code in MYSQL and all the sites structure is based like this.

Examples or demo sites would also be helpful.

Thanks a lot

Comment: `VALUES ('?','?','?')` <- You don't quote parameter markers. Simply use `VALUES (?, ?, ?)`

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to learn **PDO(PHP Data Objects)** instead of **MySQLi** cause PDO supports **12 different database** drivers while MySQLi only support MySQL Database.
To know the ***difference*** between **PDO** and **MySQLi** visit-
[PDO vs. MySQLi: Which Should You Use?](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059)
To learn about **PDO** visit this very nice tutorials-
1.[Why you Should be using PHP's PDO for Database Access](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) 

2.[PHP Database Access: Are You Doing It Correctly?](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338)

Answer (score 0):

Your table needs to have a password column as well.

HTML log in form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="email" />
 <input type="text" name="password" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
```

Catch it in the PHP file:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass = $_POST['password'];
 if($email != '' && $pass != '') { //both not empty, proceed
  $checkUser = $sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? AND `pass` = ?");
  $checkUser->bind_param('ss', $email, $pass);
  $checkUser->execute();
  if($checkUser->num_rows() > 0) { //if user exists with given email and pass
   $_SESSION['logged-in'] = 1;
  }
 }
}
```

Make sure you put `session_start();` at the top of each PHP file. Then you simply use

```
if($_SESSION['logged-in'] == 1) {
 echo 'this is for logged in users';
} else {
 header("Location: notMember.php");
 exit();
}
```

Comment: THANKS M8
 Is there some way to use the old style mysql layout like: 

    <?php session start if logged in show the page html with echos> 
    <select from users where username SESSION USER>
    <body>
    
    HELLO <PHP ECHO USERNAME> <PHP ECHO AGE> <PHP ECHO ANYTHING FROM DB> 
    THANKS
    </body>
    
    <?php
    ELSE
    IF USER IS NOT LOGGED IN
    REDIRECT TO THE PAGE NOTMEMBER.PHP
    ?>